# What *piecewise* smooth curves/surfaces/hypersurfaces give rise to forward-invariant regions of dynamical systems?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-topology, differential-equations

Consider a set $\mathcal{B}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ that is homeomorphic to a closed n-dimensional ball, and denote its boundary by $\mathcal{H}$. Assume that $\mathcal{H}$ is a "piecewise smooth" hypersurface (the meaning of "piecewise smooth" here is a bit flexible, because this will be part of the question; but, for example, we may assume that $\mathcal{H}$ is smooth everywhere except along a finite union of codimension-two manifolds).

Consider also a dynamical system $$\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x)$$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, generated by a smooth vector field $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, such that at every smooth point $x$ of $\mathcal{H}$ the vector $f(x)$ points **strictly** towards the interior of the set $\mathcal{B}$ (i.e., the dot product between $f(x)$ and the inner normal vector of $\mathcal{H}$ at $x$ is strictly positive).

My question is: ***for what class of "piecewise smooth" hypersurfaces $\mathcal{H}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ can we conclude that $\mathcal{B}$ must be a forward-invariant set of this dynamical system?***

For example: do the hypotheses described above already imply that $\mathcal{B}$ is a forward-invariant region? If not, then ***what additional hypotheses*** do we need to add in order to be able to conclude that? For example, do we need to strengthen the "piecewise smooth" hypothesis somehow, or do we need to add additional hypotheses about $f(x)$ at the points where $\mathcal{H}$ is not smooth, or something else?

More technical: would it help if we made the additional assumption that $\mathcal{H}$ is a finite union of ***smooth*** "manifolds with corners" that only intersect with each-other along their boundaries, and, additionally, that $f(x)$ points inside $\mathcal{B}$ ***everywhere***, when restricted to each one of these manifolds with corners? (In this case, for each one of these manifolds with corners $\mathcal{C_i}$, we could assume that there is a well-defined normal vector, not only at its smooth points, but also at any boundary point $y \in \partial \mathcal{C_i}$; also, if a point $y$ belongs to several $\mathcal{C_i}$'s, then we could assume that the dot product between $f(x)$ and ***all*** these inner normal vectors of $\mathcal{H}$ at $y$ is strictly positive).

Simple example: for $n=2$, $\mathcal{B}$ could be the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Its boundary has only 4 non-smooth points. On the other hand, this $\mathcal{B}$ is itself a manifold with corners, so it is quite special. To make it less special, we could imagine that we "pinch" one corner so it becomes the set $\mathcal{B}^*$ that has an "angle of size zero" at that corner, i.e., the two adjacent sides now meet tangentially (not transversally) at that corner. Then it looks easier for a trajectory of a dynamical system to escape $\mathcal{B}^*$ via the "pinched" corner (to be clear, the pinched corner looks locally kind of like the graph of $\sqrt{|x|}$). This example suggests to me that maybe additional hypotheses ***are*** required.